# Flash HTTP streaming

Tags: flash, streaming

I read Flash 10.1 supports HTTP adaptive streaming.
Can you give me an example code? Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check out OSMF, a full featured Media playback framework that supports HTTP Dynamic streams: http://www.opensourcemediaframework.com/index.php

Here is a link to some sample code using that feature in the framework: http://labs.almerblank.com/2010/04/dynamic-streaming-in-osmf-10/